# Reading order of Warhammer Fantasy Time of Legends Books?

Tags: suggested-order, warhammer-fantasy

Anyone have a reading order for the time of legends books?

Answer (score 1):

From the [LibraryThink](https://www.librarything.com/series/Time+of+Legends) website, the following reading order is listed as:

```
Titles                              Order

Heldenhammer (by Graham McNeill)    1.1
Empire (by Graham McNeill)          1.2
God King (by Graham McNeill)        1.3
Nagash the Sorcerer (by Mike Lee)   2.1
Nagash the Unbroken (by Mike Lee)   2.2
Nagash Immortal (by Mike Lee)       2.3
Malekith (by Gav Thorpe)            3.1
Shadow King (by Gav Thorpe)         3.2
Caledor (by Gav Thorpe)             3.3
The Sundering (by Gav Thorpe)       Omnbus 3.1 - 3.3
Dead Winter (by C. L. Werner)       4.1
Blighted Empire (by C. L. Werner)   4.2
The Great Betrayal (by Nick Kyme)   5.1
Neferata (by Josh Reynolds)         6.1
Age of Legends (by Christian Dunn)  Anthology
```

Comment: That order is incorrect.

Comment: @AntholKinsidious - Could very well be. I will delete this if you'd like and you could post the order you believe is correct?